# Change file name <AssemblyName.exe.config> to <App.Config> for output directory in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a C# project and an App.Config file in this project. When i build the source code, a file (AssemblyName.exe.config) is created in the output directory for the application configuration but i want the name of this file App.Config. How can i do that?

Comment: Why? What's so special about naming it `App.Config` (except that it will confuse anyone who knows the standard .NET config file names _and_ break the application, unless you write specific overrides in your code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but i want the name of this file App.Config.

You can use a post-build event to rename the file.

However, realize that the application settings architecture which uses the file will expect the name to be `AssemblyName.exe.config`.  If you rename the file, the normal application settings architecture will break.

Answer (score 1):

You access in your `Application Build`, in `Event Post Build` add action who rename file.

```
rename "YourPath/AssemblyName.exe.config" "YourPath/App.Config"
```