# How can I avoid AssemblyName.exe.config confusion when extensions are hidden?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, app-config

I have an app which has a .config file. On my machine the distinction between the .exe and .config file is obvious because I have extensions turned on.

[image]

However, I don't think this is the default setting, so the average user may not see the extensions. If the "Type" column is not visible, this further adds to the confusion.

[image]

If I tell users "just unzip and run the executable file" I'm pretty sure at least some users may end up double-clicking the .config file, mistaking it for the real .exe.

What is a good way to solve this problem? I want users to be able to unzip and run my app without having to go through an installer, so using an installer to create a start menu shortcut isn't a good solution for me.

My initial thought was to see if I could rename the config file so that users wouldn't confuse it for the .exe, but that seems like [that will cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333684/change-file-name-assemblyname-exe-config-to-app-config-for-output-directory). If it matters, I use the .config file to include the `probing` tag to direct all .dll loading to the **data** folder.

Comment: I'd guess that an _average user_ keeps the `Hidden items` checkbox empty. Just _hide_ the `.config` file. Another approach: create an `Install&Run.bat` and tell users "just run the `Install&Run` item".

Comment: Hidden file - so simple and perfect, but why comment instead of answer? I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close your question as off-topic: _Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)_.  However, that idea _could_ be useful for another questioner. Please [**make your own answer** and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) till possible (after 48 hours IMHO).

Comment: Thanks - also I believed that it may "involve tools used primarily for programming" if it there was some setting in Visual Studio to change the file name that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by JosefZ, the .config file can be marked as hidden which will prevent it from showing up on the average user's machine.